# Automatic deployments with Gitlab (and possibly Ansible)

Tags: git, deployment, ansible, gitlab

Thanks for taking the time to read my question. I'm looking for a little **direction from experience** with a new workflow. I have recently been updating things and added Ansible for some devops tasks as well as moved our repos to a dedicated GitLab server.

**Current nodes**:

- 5 production servers
- 2 development servers
- 2 DB servers
- 1 dedicated Gitlab server hosting repos for all sites
- 1 Ansible control server (with all boxes in inventory)

What I am trying to accomplish is an automated process but am not sure if I should be using standard webhooks, runners or if possibly I should hook into our Ansible control server to manage deployment tasks.

**Basically, each repo has a `master` (production) and `develop` (development) branches.** I want to deploy the `develop` branch AUTOMATICALLY when someone pushes to this branch. Additionally, I want to deploy `master` into production MANUALLY when a merge request is approved and merged into our production line.

I'm new to Ansible and have things working well right now with devops tasks but am unsure regarding it's potential with Git and a situation like mine. Any direction from someone with experience would be incredibly helpful and most appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this post (I won't even call it a question) does not meet the criteria listed in the [don't ask section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)? Even most of them?

Comment: Setting up a personal CI/CD for your business needs is rather extensive for a SO question.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a drawn out answer but more of an educated reply as to the viability (or lack thereof) of using Ansible with a git workflow such as mine.

Comment: Yes: it is completely possible.

Comment: I figured out CI this morning using Ansible. SO...useful as always, lol.

Answer (score 0):

We use ansible for deployments on all sort of servers. Ansible has got good integration with git, git is inbuilt module in Ansible. All you need is some snippet like this in your ansible playbook:

```
- git: repo=<your_git_repo> dest=<destination_directory_for_code> clone=yes version={{ branch_name }} depth=1
  tags:
   - <any_tags>
  sudo: no
```

**From my experience, I can tell you 2 things:**

1. deploying only branch that's required and not cloning the entire repo helps, especially when the repo is big. (shown in above code)
2. using depth=1 specifies that you essentially keep commit log of just the last commit made. This not just helps in keeping the clone size smaller but also to know what was the last commit made in order to figure out if the deployed code is proper.

On the automatic deployment part, you can keep the same scripts on your CI, may be jenkins / bamboo / travis ci / any other ci to keep polling particular branches for any changes in the same deployment jobs. Each ci has got good integration with git (Jenkins git plugin for example).

The **I'm feeling lucky google result** shows [Example Provisioning and Deployment using ANsible](https://www.stavros.io/posts/example-provisioning-and-deployment-ansible/) which I found to be really interesting.

I'll recommend you to go through ansible documentation one it's pretty extensive. I personally use ansible command line documentation itself :)

Hope this helps.

Edit:
I forgot to add that the git plugin works perfectly fine with github/gitlab/bitbucket, so you can use git plugin in ci for gitlab without any issues.